# Show that $r^l, r^{-l-1}$ are solutions to $\frac{1}{R}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\frac{dR}{dr}\right)=l(l+1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, power-series

`Here is a standard textbook question that is causing great difficulty (even though the question says it is easy):`

[image: Textbook question 11]

I'm only interested in finding the solution to the second of the above $2$ differential equations by using a **power series** method:
$$\frac{1}{R}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\frac{dR}{dr}\right)=l(l+1)\tag{1}$$
which has solutions $$R=\begin{cases} r^l \\  r^{-l-1} \end{cases}\tag{2}$$ (as printed in the back of the book)

`Attempt #1:`

Let $$R=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n\cdot r^n\tag{3}$$ where the $C_n$ are the expansion coefficients.

Then $$\frac{dR}{dr}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n\cdot n\,r^{n-1}\tag{4}$$

and $$\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty C_n \cdot n(n-1)r^{n-2}\tag{5}$$

Re-writing $(1)$ via the product rule

$$2r\frac{dR}{dr}+r^2\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}=R\,l(l+1)\tag{6}$$

Now substituting $(3)$, $(4)$ and $(5)$ into $(6)$

$$2r\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n \cdot n\,r^{n-1}+r^2\sum_{n=2}^\infty C_n \cdot n(n-1)\,r^{n-2}=l(l+1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \cdot r^{n}\tag{7}$$

I am unsure how to proceed from here to show that $$R=\begin{cases} r^l \\  r^{-l-1} \end{cases}\tag{2}$$

Could someone please give me some hints or advice on how I can proceed to reach $(2)$?

---

### EDIT:

Proceeding with the advice given in the first comment by using the method of Frobenius:

`Attempt #2:`

Letting $$R=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n\cdot r^{s+n}\tag{A}$$ where the $C_n$ are the expansion coefficients.

Then $$\frac{dR}{dr}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n\cdot (s+n)\,r^{s+n-1}\tag{B}$$

and $$\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \cdot (s+n)(s+n-1)\,r^{s+n-2}\tag{C}$$

Writing out the sums explicitly:

$$R=C_0\cdot r^s+C_1\cdot r^{s+1}+C_2\cdot r^{s+2}+C_3\cdot r^{s+3}+\cdots+C_n\cdot r^{s+n}$$

$$\frac{dR}{dr} = C_0\cdot s\,r^{s-1}+C_1\cdot(s+1)\,r^s + C_2\cdot(s+2)\,r^{s+1}+C_3\cdot(s+3)\,r^{s+2}\quad+\cdots + C_n\cdot(s+n)\, r^{s+n-1}$$

$$\frac{d^2R}{dr^2} = C_0\cdot s(s-1)\,r^{s-2}+C_1\cdot s(s+1)\,r^{s-1} + C_2\cdot(s+1)(s+2)\,r^s\quad +C_3\cdot(s+2)(s+3)\,r^{s+1}+\cdots + C_n\cdot(s+n)(s+n-1)r^{s+n-2}$$

Therefore

$$2r\frac{dR}{dr}=2C_0\cdot sr^s+2C_1\cdot (s+1)r^{s+1}+2C_2\cdot(s+2) r^{s+2}+2C_3\cdot(s+3)r^{s+3}\quad+\cdots+2C_n\cdot(s+n) r^{s+n}$$

$$r^2\frac{d^2R}{dr^2} = C_0\cdot s(s-1)\,r^{s}+C_1\cdot s(s+1)\,r^{s+1} + C_2\cdot(s+1)(s+2)\,r^{s+2}\quad + C_3\cdot(s+2)(s+3)\,r^{s+3}+\cdots + C_n\cdot(s+n)(s+n-1)\, r^{s+n}$$

$$l(l+1)R=l(l+1)C_0\cdot r^s+l(l+1)C_1\cdot r^{s+1}+l(l+1)C_2\cdot r^{s+2}+l(l+1)C_3\cdot r^{s+3}+\cdots+l(l+1)C_n\cdot r^{s+n}$$

Now rewriting equation $(6)$:

$$2r\frac{dR}{dr}+r^2\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}=R\,l(l+1)$$

in terms of summations gives

$$2r\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \cdot (s+n)\,r^{s+n-1}+r^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \cdot (n+s)(n+s-1)\,r^{s+n-2}=l(l+1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \cdot r^{s+n}$$

by bringing in the $r$'s into the sums for the first two summations on the LHS I find that

$$2\sum_{n=-1}^\infty C_{n+1}  (s+n+1)r^{s+n}+\sum_{n=-2}^\infty C_{n+2}(s+n+2)(s+n+1)r^{s+n}=l(l+1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n  r^{s+n}$$
by shifting the index from $n\rightarrow n-1$ and $n\rightarrow n-2$ for the first and second sums respectively.

Now that the powers of $r$ are the same I can compare coefficients:

For $$n \ge -1\implies 2C_{n+1}\cdot(s+n+1)=l(l+1)\cdot C_n$$

For $$n \ge -2\implies 2C_{n+1}\cdot(s+n+1)+C_{n+2}\cdot(s+n+2)(s+n+1)=l(l+1)\cdot C_n$$

But how do I get the *Indical equation* from here to find the value of $s$?

---

Thank you.

Comment: When you substitute equations $3, 4$ and $5$ into $6$, you have shifted your summation to start at $n=0$ for the $R''$ and $R'$ series. They should still start at $n = 2$ and $n = 1$ respectively. Also, you'll want to use the [Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) to find a power series solution to your problem as a normal ansatz won't work due to the pole at $r = 0$.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by there is a "pole at $r=0$", isn't this always the case for $n=0$? Not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Your ODE as you have it written is

$$r^{2} R'' + 2r R' = Rl(l+1)$$

(Alternatively, divide through your ODE by $r^{2}$ to get it in a different form). What happens to your ODE when $r = 0$?

Comment: @Mattos There is no solution when $r=0$, is that correct? But what does "pole" mean in this context? Thanks again.

Comment: @Mattos I cannot get the Frobenius method to work either, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is it a given that one must assume a "power series solution"? Or rather, a "power solution"? I am asking because the usual approach is to look for solutions $R(r)=r^a$ and to simply check that these functions are indeed solutions if and only if $a=\ell$ or $a=-\ell-1$, end of the exercise. To sum up, the sentence before your (1) and (2) does not correspond to the text of exercise 11 and the strategy it suggests is not needed.

Comment: @Did It's a power series solution as the whole chapter for which that question is asked under is regarding power series solutions (Legendre, Bessel, Laguerre, Frobenius etc.) to differential equations.

Comment: Second try: is the sentence "By assuming a power series solution show that the solution..." due to you, or is it written exactly as it is, in the book?

Comment: @Did Oh sorry, now i understand you. It is due to me. I will remove the quote box so there is no further ambiguity....

Comment: Good idea to get rid of it since it asks something different from the book. Note that: 1. my first comment is a full solution to what the book actually asks; 2. the formulation you introduced ("By assuming a power series solution show that the solution to ... is ...") was even difficult to interpret since there are other solutions than $R(r)=r^\ell$ and $R(r)=r^{-\ell-1}$, for example $R(r)=2r^\ell+5r^{-\ell-1}$.

Comment: Not sure I got the point through so let me repeat it differently: do you understand that everything in your post starting at `Attempt #1:` is off-topic?

Comment: @Did No, I think what I wrote is on-topic. You seem to have interpreted the question as "verify $r^l$ and $r^{-l-1}$" are solutions. That was not my interpretation of the question. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The text says: "you could use power series method; given the fact that the solutions are just powers of $r$, it is easy to find the powers". Hence, yes, you *could* embark on the full power series method, which works if done carefully enough, naturally, and you *would* arrive at the conclusion that every power series solution is a linear combination of two power solutions. Or, you can use the second part of the sentence and look directly for power solutions, getting a complete and short solution. Since I do not like to waste my time, I would go for the second option (just a personal choice).

Comment: @Did Thank you for taking the time to explain that, and yes I agree with you that taking the second part of the question is faster (but only if you know what you're doing, which I don't). I am a student, so I have no choice but to go with the first part of the question; Which I have tried by general ansatz in #1 and Frobenius' method in #2 both have failed and I _need_ to know what I am doing wrong, otherwise I won't learn anything.

Comment: The step "bringing in the r's into the sums for the first two summations on the LHS" is faulty, for example, the first term on the left is $$2r\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \cdot (s+n)\,r^{s+n-1}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \cdot (s+n)\,r^{s+n},$$ likewise for the other terms, hence your shift indexes are (wrong and) offtopic.

Comment: @Did Thanks that was helpful; I thought I had to change the index of summation?

Comment: @BLAZE: (+1) for your intensive elaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did has already explained in the comments that it makes more sense to use a single power *ansatz* than a power series. If you really want to use a power series, you have to include negative powers if you want to get the $r^{-l-1}$ solution, since this can't be written as a series of non-negative powers at $r=0$.

In the equation you derived, pulling the extra powers of $r$ into the sums leads to all three sums having the same power $r^n$. Then equating the coefficients for all powers yields

$$
C_n(2n+n(n-1))=C_nl(l+1)\;,
$$

or

$$
C_n(n(n+1)-l(l+1))=0\;.
$$

It follows that for each $n$ either $C_n=0$ or $n(n+1)=l(l+1)$. The latter equation has the two solutions $n=l$ and $n=-l-1$, so those are the only two powers that can have non-zero coefficients, and the general solution is a linear combination of the two.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1); the strange thing is that the original version of my question led to the equation $n(n+1)=l(l+1)$ but I got told that this was wrong due to the first comment by Mattos: who says that I must use the method of Frobenius to solve the problem. Supposing that I did use the method of Frobenius: Would the sums have to be from $-\infty\to\infty$? If you could please elaborate on this a little in your answer that would be great, as the objective is to reach the same answer using both methods. Thanks.

Comment: @BLAZE: I disagree that you "must" use any particular method. It's a second-order linear differential equation, so the solution space is a two-dimensional vector space, so you obtain the general solution by finding any two independent solutions. How you find them is entirely up to you. You can use individual powers, a power series starting at some variable finite exponent or a power series with exponents from $-\infty$ to $\infty$; all of these will yield the solution. What you can't do is to use a power series starting at exponent $0$, since that misses the solution with negative exponent.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and taking the time to answer; it is appreciated.

Comment: @BLAZE _I_ didn't say you _had_ to use a power series solution, _you_ said _you wanted_ to use one. I said _if_ you are going to use a power series solution, you must use a different power series ansatz to the one you used, namely the one used in the Frobenius method. You really didn't understand my comments at all.

Comment: @Mattos I guess I didn't understand the comments then; but on the other hand it is hard to understand your comments when you don't reply to my comments; for instance: "What do you mean by there is a pole at $r=0$" has been ignored.

Comment: @BLAZE I don't spend every waking hour on this site, so if I don't write back it is probably because I haven't been on. Feel free to research peoples suggestions yourself next time though.